# Not able to scrape 'Delivery Date' from flipkart

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the BeautifulSoup library in Python to scrape data from flipkart. 
The data to be scrapped from the website looks as follows:

[image: HTML file that needs to be scraped]

I implemented the following code to get the delivery date:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    f = open("file3.txt",'w')
    request = requests.get("http://www.flipkart.com/huawei-stainless-steel-black-leather-strap-smartwatch/p/itmeftxerghg4pqx?pid=SMWEFTXEXRDXMYGR&al=o3IgYeHw27sSnkNXR1et9sldugMWZuE7eGHgUTGjVrpdmSA7vzZ7axnEa%2FFU%2FfOBK%2FKVBvTcIys%3D&ref=L%3A4088879532713987740&srno=b_1").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request)
    for classs in soup.findAll('div',class_ = 'delivery'):
       for li in classs.find_all('li'):
           f.write(str(li.text))
    f.close()
```

Running this code, I get the following output in a text file:

"Usually Delivered in 6-7 business days."

The text above is not present in the html file at all.

My guess is that "delivered by" is not usual like the rest. I don't understand why the "delivered by" option is not getting scrapped.

[image: this is how the data looks in the website]

From experience of online ordering, I think delivered by date usually changes according to location or time ordered. Does this impact?
Can some one please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Delivered By detailed information (by clicking the question mark)? One thing it mentions is that 'the delivery time will be mentioned as based on your location pincode' for which there is an input box

Comment: Yes there is  input box where the pincode needs to be typed in. But how do we scrape the delivery date after that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the pincode as a request param at the end of the product URL. You should now see the delivery date for that pincode.

Original

> http://www.flipkart.com/puma-917-lo-dp-low-ankle-sneakers/p/itmecrtxysm37ygh?pid=SHOEAJU6J79GGA2H&otracker=reco_pp_same_womenfw_shoe_4&ppid=SHOEFHZ3XZGGARDY

Modified

> http://www.flipkart.com/puma-917-lo-dp-low-ankle-sneakers/p/itmecrtxysm37ygh?pid=SHOEAJU6J79GGA2H&otracker=reco_pp_same_womenfw_shoe_4&ppid=SHOEFHZ3XZGGARDY&pincode=456001